# long press and drag event in react.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to achieve below interaction using react. But I don't know what event to be used.

[image]

It's long press and drag. But I couldn't find any references or example or library to continue. I only manage to do a hover effect

https://fiddle.jshell.net/8wsr7xa1/

```
<div>
    {items.map((obj,i) =>  
        <div 
        key={i} 
        style={this.state.active === obj ? 
        {backgroundColor: 'yellow'} : {}} 
        onMouseEnter={this.onMouseEnter.bind(this, obj)}>
        {obj}
        </div>
     )}
</div>
```

Comment: You will need to use onMouseDown and onMouseUp and track the dragging cells covered for every mouse move. This is complicated and too broad for stackoverflow

Comment: This is a great use case for RxJS

Comment: @AndyRay too broad? I already mentioned what I want to achieve. I thought of long press and drag and came up with a hover as starter. But I couldn't proceed..

Comment: @CodinCat seriously? can't accomplish this in normal react?

Comment: Of course you can. Just like @AndyRay described above. You need onMouseDown, onMouseUp and onMouseMove events

Answer (score 0):

From the view of the calendar you have, I'm assuming you have some type of conditions applied on the days that are greyed out (they shouldn't be selected).
Crediting RoshanJossey, he created a react event listner for long press with an editable threshold https://codesandbox.io/s/uselongpress-oekx2?file=/src/useLongPress.js
You should supply your calendar divs with this event (longClick) and have a state defaulted to false

```
const [isLongClickTriggered, setIsLongClickTriggered] = useState(false)
```

whenever the long click event is registered you should change this state to true. Afterwards you can have the calendar divs be selected on hover as your demo initiates as long as another click is not registered.
The calendar divs that were selected can then be stored in a seperate state as well.

```
const longPressEvent = useLongPress(onLongPress, onClick, defaultOptions);
.
.
.
<div>
    {items.map((obj,i) =>  
        <div 
        key={i} 
        style={this.state.active === obj ? 
        {backgroundColor: 'yellow'} : {}} 
         {...longPressEvent}>
        {obj}
        </div>
     )}
</div>
```